# what's wrong with installation of "Rglpk" on mac?

Tags: r, macos

```
> install.packages("Rglpk")
Package which is only available in source
  form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rglpk’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘Rglpk’

试开URL’https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rglpk_0.6-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 20892 bytes (20 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 20 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Rglpk’ ...
** 成功将‘Rglpk’程序包解包并MD5和检查
** libs
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: GLPK: No such file or directory
make: *** [GLPK.ts] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rglpk’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rglpk’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rglpk’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Rglpk’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/b2/ph_1yql507ddv6d659lcm99h0000gn/T/Rtmpfm2CvV/downloaded_packages’
```

My RStudio is all new( just downloaded today )
Thanks !

Comment: Before you can install this R package you must install GLPK on your system.

Answer (score 1):

`rglpk` is a mere interface to the `GMPK` library, which must be installed on the system prior to installing `rglpk`. For MacOS, you can install it with [Homebrew](http://braumeister.org/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-science/formula/glpk), or [install it manually](http://arnab-deka.com/posts/2010/02/installing-glpk-on-a-mac/).