# Error installing Rglpk package in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, homebrew, glpk

I tried installing the `Rglpk` package using:

```
install.packages("Rglpk")
```

but got following message:

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
C/C++/Fortran: 'Rglpk'
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package 'Rglpk'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rglpk_0.6-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 20892 bytes (20 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 20 KB

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* installing *source* package 'Rglpk' ...
** package 'Rglpk' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
Error in dyn.load("conftest.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/kg/05p23mln6bg7rt8d3jryc30w0000gn/T/RtmpXw7Z3J/R.INSTALL282d4ddc1f3b/Rglpk/conftest.so':
  dlopen(/private/var/folders/kg/05p23mln6bg7rt8d3jryc30w0000gn/T/RtmpXw7Z3J/R.INSTALL282d4ddc1f3b/Rglpk/conftest.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/glpk/lib/libglpk.40.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Execution halted
** libs
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: GLPK: No such file or directory
make: *** [GLPK.ts] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rglpk'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rglpk'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'Rglpk' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/private/var/folders/kg/05p23mln6bg7rt8d3jryc30w0000gn/T/RtmpHmhPNf/downloaded_packages'
```

I used `brew` to install `glpk`. Although there were some issues with the link, it seems to have worked:

```
MacOS USER$ brew link glpk
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/glpk/4.65... 5 symlinks created
```

Any ideas to what is going wrong?

Comment: I guess you don't have required C files set up for building software on your OsX, but brew did it for you, so answer and accept your solution with using brew to achieve the result, your last code entry, and that will close out this question, and you'll earn some points.

Comment: Pierre, you solved your problem. Write your solution `MacOS USER$ brew link glpk
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/glpk/4.65... 5 symlinks created` in Your Answer, and accept your own answer. Then the question, which has a solution, won't linger as an unanswered question.

Comment: It's not working, i still have the same message in R. Exactly the same.

Comment: I had this error message in R, i google it and i found the brew solution i installed it. But still it's not working and i don't understand what i did with brew and what it is supposed to do. I think there is an issue with the path because of this line in the error:  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/glpk/lib/libglpk.40.dylib
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Please can sonmeone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Your last homebrew command installed the glpk library, I think, and next step, according to [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728918/whats-wrong-with-installation-of-rglpk-on-mac?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) is to run this into Terminal `xcode-select --install` and it should install fine.

Comment: thank you for your help, here is what i get: MacBook-Air-de-User:MacOS User$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: MacBook-Air-de-User:MacOS USER$ brew link glpk
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/glpk/4.65 so it seems to be linked how R know where to find it ? as it doesn't seem to be the same path in the error message from R studio

Answer (score 0):

Had the same pronlem, in addition to installing GLPK via homebrew,you need to activate the dependencies. type in the R console the following after installing Rglpk via the R console and glpk via homebrew:

install.packages("Rglpk", dependencies=TRUE)

That should do the trick